# How to create list of object in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to create list of object in jquery ?
Example:

Object name: rowdataObject having properties.

NOw, i want to create list of rowdataObject and pass to MVC.

Please suggest me how to create list of object in javascript and pass as argument in controller.

Thanks

Comment: This question is a bit underrated for this site, but I'll attempt to give you a small example. Keep in mind for future use tho, we generally like to see "what you have tried" first.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {  //  this is jQuery's version of `document.onload = function` which basically means, "start doing this when page is loaded"
                //  an Object in jQuery is extremely simple in nature
                var obj = {};   //  this is officially an object
                //  add to the object by simply creating properties
                obj.prop1 = "This  property is a string";
                //  add inner objects just as easy
                obj.class1 = { prop1: "This inner object now has it's own property" }

                //  to pass this to a "controller" in jQuery, you will use a form of $.ajax
                $.ajax({    //  here you start creating ajax options
                    type: 'POST',   //  makes this retrievable via POST on server side, exp: $_POST['keyName']
                    data: JSON.stringify({ keyName: obj }), //  easiest way to send data as key|value
                    url: 'http://www.example.com'   //  here you need the url to your controller
                })  //  now, use jQuery chainability to see results returned from controller
                    .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                        //  this function will fire only if the controller makes a successful return
                        /*  do work, exp:   */
                        console.log(data); //   this would show the results of what the controller returned in your browser's developer console
                    })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

---

### References

- [JS Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [jQuery's Chainability](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)
- [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: How can i create list of obj. I have obj which has properites as below: obj.name,obj.ID,obj.mins. Now, i want to create colleectionof obj and pass to controller method. Please suggest.

Comment: Is Json.Stringify will able to pass - collection of object to controller function ? what should be the argument in controller function - "Jsondata" ?